Configure adb to only ever run under root privilege
When an adb command accidentally gets executed without the adb daemon running, it tries to automatically start the daemon under whatever privilege was available for the original command. This doesn't work, because all my adb commands are executed by ordinary users, whereas the adb daemon cannot find connected android devices unless it is started by the system root user. Is it possible to either (a) prevent commands from attempting to smart-start the daemon, or (b) to configure the daemon to always prompt for a root password and elevate before executing?
There doesn't seem to be any channel for communicating with Google development about this sort of issue, and in any case they have very high confidence in whatever decisions they happen to hand down. So a workaround such as (a) or (b) seems likely to be the most productive approach.

Update: Host platform is headless Fedora 41 workstation on x86-64, where adb is always used from a developer account except just to start the daemon.

Update: Fixed according to a previous answer using a udev rule to make the device available for my development user's group, which avoids root privilege in the normal adb workflow.

What operating system is your development host? The question reads like Linux, in which case you could setuid the adb executable to root, although many organisations would object to that.

My solution to this problem on Linux is based on the idea that the only account that uses my Android build machine daily is the account used to do central builds and run tests on them. That account was given no-password sudo rights on the Android build machine, and when it sets up our Android build environment, that checks if adbd is running as non-root and if so, kills it and starts it as root with sudo. If any other user starts our Android build environment and it finds adbd running as non-root, it tells the user to ask for help.. This works pretty well for us.

I a not a Linux user (at least not with adb) but I remember that the correct solution is to adapt access permissions (udev rules) of the device because adb and adb-server are by default running with user permissions. This is the way it is designed. See also the non-sudo answers to https://stackoverflow.com/q/14460656/150978

I think you should fix this part as Robert suggested: "adb daemon cannot find connected android devices unless it is started by the system root user".
